# How to deal with the Large number of negative samples in unet training

Tags: image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am doing a task of segmenting the brain tumor with unet，but I just get the result with all black。But when I delete all negative samples the net will get some good result。

How should I deal with these negative samples？Is there some good loss function to handle this problem？